# Dragon Ball Xenoverse 2 - Z Rank

Tags: dragon-ball-xenoverse-2

I am trying to get Z rank in all quests, but I can't seem to get Z rank in the third training quest for Gotenks (the one where you fight the Cell Juniors).

I can complete the quest with:

- More than 80% HP
- Finish with Super Attack
- Kill 10 enemies with 10 Supers
- Hit 10 Supers
- Grab 3 Times
- Destroy 10 objects
- Hit 20 ki blasts
- Hit a 20 combo

And currently I can't remember no more, but even with the above I can't get Z rank. What else can I do to improve my score? Any tips for this quest?

**EDIT:**
Tried to use the "40 tons weitgh" Z-Soul, but it seems that this only change de experience and not the score itself.
My best score at this mission is around 8600... I'm pretty sure I am close to Z rank, but no luck until now...

**EDIT 2:** Just managed to complete the mission with 2 more bonuses:

- Hit behind 10 times
- Perfect block 3 times

Wans't enough yet: 8900 points... S Rank

Is there any list with all the accolades for this game?

**EDIT 3:** Complete all the above with:

- Finish in the last 10 seconds

9230 points and still S Rank... I'm starting to believe it's not possible to get Z Rank in this mission.

Answer (score 1):

Finish with:

- 10 seconds left Timely
- 3 just guards (guard exactly when they hit you)
- 20 ki blast repel

Use super soul or item to het your health over 80% before mission ends (get all the accolades that you listed). You don't need to go untouchable in this and even if you do you need to get other accolades also: Good luck!